# Stacking gradients and blend-modes

Tags: layers, gradient, css, blend-modes

## Desired result

I'm trying to stack some CSS gradients together to replicate a fill pattern from Excel.

[image: From Center, Red on Blue]

## Problem

I have something that almost works, but it requires additional HTML elements and I'm not too sure I'm using `blend-mode` correctly.
I know you can specify multiple `background-blend-mode` in CSS, but I can't manage to make them work together on a single element.

## My solution so far

I was able to get a decent solution using nested elements and two layers.

### Using white as an intermediate step

The first layer uses `background-blend-mode: darken;` with white and blue.
My solution looks a little bit different, but here is how Excel would show it:

[image: From Center, White on Blue]

My HTML/CSS: [codepen link](https://codepen.io/jeanbern/pen/BaPeaQj)

```html
<div class="example"></div>
```

```css
.example {
  --middle-color: #FFFFFF;
  --outer-color: #4472C4;
  width: 500px;
  height: 150px;
  background:
      linear-gradient(to right, var(--outer-color), var(--middle-color) 50%, var(--outer-color) 100%),
      linear-gradient(to bottom, var(--outer-color), var(--middle-color) 50%, var(--outer-color) 100%);
  background-blend-mode: darken;
}
```

### Using white again, then stacking

To make the red portion, I again use white, but this time with `background-blend-mode: lighten;`
Finally, I combine the two layers with `mix-blend-mode`

Here is the implementation: [codepen link](https://codepen.io/jeanbern/pen/qBywZzQ)

```html
<div class="example">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.example {
  --middle-color: #FFFFFF;
  --outer-color: #4472C4;
  width: 500px;
  height: 150px;
  background:
      linear-gradient(to right, var(--outer-color), var(--middle-color) 50%, var(--outer-color) 100%),
      linear-gradient(to bottom, var(--outer-color), var(--middle-color) 50%, var(--outer-color) 100%);
  background-blend-mode: darken;
}
.inner {
  --middle-color: red;
  --outer-color: #FFFFFF;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
    background:
      linear-gradient(to right, var(--outer-color), var(--middle-color) 50%, var(--outer-color) 100%),
      linear-gradient(to bottom, var(--outer-color), var(--middle-color) 50%, var(--outer-color) 100%);
    background-blend-mode: lighten;
    mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

I'm not 100% sure that `mix-blend-mode: multiply;` is the correct choice, but I am a software developer who has not studied graphic design and blending at all.

Comment: This is more like a coding question, made to sound like a design question.

Comment: It's not something I'd readily expect a developer to know. Sure it's generated using _code_, but the language and subject matter seem graphical to me.  
I use SO a lot and didn't expect it to be answerable there, so I came here.

Comment: Well, maybe somebody will answer this. If you need a random designer opinion, all the images in the post look like something from the 90's. Can you achieve that with code ? Maybe, but sometimes less is more.

Comment: Are we supposed to download some file and dig through it to understand "Is there a way to achieve this exact look in CSS?" Can you not post an image/screenshot of the "exact look" you are trying to achieve?

Comment: this is a tricky issue, i dont expect this to have a super fruitful answer as: graphic designers generally dont touch suff like this very often. And in anycase arent big on microsoft tools. athis isnt a very interesting problem outside of software development.

Comment: @Lucian Noted. My job is just to replicate these effects, I know they're ugly!  
Scott Scenario 1 shows the exact look I'm trying to achieve. The download link is for completeness.  
joojaa You don't have to read the specification document; That's just some background into the motivation. You also don't need to use microsoft tools, I provided the desired result images.

Comment: I'll wait a day and if the response continues to be less than encouraging I'll delete this and go back to my cave on SO.

Comment: There are multiple approaches and questions here. Try to hone in on the one thing you're actually wanting aid with. What is that thing? Then edit your question to be more clear about that aspect

Comment: Just off the top pf my head.. perhaps creating the "X" via CSS then blurring it would achieve desired results (although be more intensive to render.) Gradients are really just blurred colors. I don't really see another solution myself. Graphic designers aren't often delving into advanced CSS methodology.. some do. But it's not overly common.

Comment: Can't you use a raster image as the background? This would be trivial in software such as Photoshop/GIMP using the gradient tool. If you export as a good quality jpeg it should more or less be indistinguishable from something coded in the browser. You could easily keep the file size low, if that's an issue.

Comment: @BillyKerr It's all generated on the fly, with user configurable colors and gradient paths. Maybe I can do it with an svg or something. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: Yes it could be done in SVG without any blend modes. [see example here](https://svgshare.com/i/q8T.svg). I used three squares, one red base rect, and two on top with a blue to transparent blue gradient.